# How can I disable Yubikey's OTP?

Tags: yubikey

I'm using a Yubikey and it is going wild: because of a bad contact, it relentlessly types every 3 seconds a code like this one on my interface:

```
cccjgjgkhcbbirdrfdnlnghhfgrtnnlgedjlftrdafe
```

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it this way:

1. Install yubikey-manager:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt install yubikey-manager
   ```
2. Plug your yubikey inside the USB port
3. Add the yubikey
4. Finally:

   ```bsh
   $ ykman config usb --disable otp  # for Yubikey version > 4
   Disable OTP.
   Configure USB interface? [y/N]: y
   ```

   I had a Yubikey 4 and for this version, the above command did not work:

   ```
   Error: Configuring applications is not supported on this YubiKey. Use the `mode` command to configure USB interfaces.
   ```

   Just do:

   ```bsh
   $ ykman mode FIDO+CCID  # for Yubikey version == 4
   Set mode of YubiKey to FIDO+CCID? [y/N]: y
   Mode set! You must remove and re-insert your YubiKey for this change to take effect.
   ```